# Is there anyway to access es6 constant by variable?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

Is there anyway to access ES6 constant by variable?

For ex.

```
const OPEN_TAB = 0;
const CLOSE_TAB = 1;

let action = 'OPEN';

console.log(window[`${action}_TAB`]); <-- something like that
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is not (*). `const` declarations do not become properties of the global object.

You need to find another solution, such as creating an object and freeze it (to make it immutable):

```
const TAB = Object.freeze({
  OPEN: 0,
  CLOSE: 1,
});

console.log(TAB[action]);
```

---

I'd argue that relying on global variables (i.e. `var`) becoming properties of the global object is bad design anyway. If you want to look something up by name you really should have something like a map or a record (as shown above).

---

*: Well, you could use `eval`...

Answer (score 0):

For the current code you have, you can use `eval` *([But take care!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea))*, it should be like this:

```js
const OPEN_TAB = 0;
const CLOSE_TAB = 1;

let action = 'OPEN';

console.log( eval (action+'_TAB') );
```

---

The other way is to assume a new object to the `const`, then you can access the `const` easily like the common way you can access to JavaScript objects:

```js
const TAB = {
OPEN:0,
CLOSE:1
};


let action = 'OPEN';


console.log(TAB[action]);
```